# Remove All Indexes in String

Tags: c#, winforms

I have dictionary of int (`Dictionary<int, int>`) which has index of all parenthesis in a string (key was `openStartParenthesisIndex` and value was `closeEndParenthesisIndex`)

e.g in text

```
stringX.stringY(())() -> stringX.stringY$($()^)^$()^
$ = openParenthesisStartIndex
^ = closeParenthesisEndIndex
```

Dictionary items:

```
             key                            value
          (openParenthesisStartIndex) --- (closeParenthesisEndIndex)
    item1    15                            19
    item2    16                            18
    item3    19                            21
```

My problem was when I loop my dictionary and try to remove it on string, next loop the index was not valid since its already change because I remove it .

```
string myText = "stringX.stringY(())()";
Dictionary<int, int> myIndexs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var x in myIndexs)
{
    myText = myText.Remove(item.Key, 1).Remove(item.Value-1);
}
```

Question: how can i remove all index in a string (from startIndex[key] to endIndex[value])?

Comment: Can't you just use `Replace` and replace all parentheses with an empty string?

Comment: I don't know how  this example could compile as x is of type `KeyValuePair<int, int>`.

Comment: Can you show some sample strings and what you expect as result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, already modified sorry about that ...

Comment: `"stringX.stringY(())()".Replace("(",string.Empty).Replace(")",string.Empty);` this will remove all your parentheses and does not require iterating a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @AndreiV, i cannot do that since all of those index was index of '(' and ')' and not all parenthesis should be replaced ... only those who have pair

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the index from changing, one trick is to remove the occurences starting from the end:

```
string myText = stringX.stringY(())();
Dictionary<int, int> myIndexs = new Dictionary<int, int>();

var allIndexes = myIndexs.Keys.Concat(myIndexs.Values);

foreach (var index in allIndexes.OrderByDescending(i => i))
{
    myText = myText.Remove(index, 1);
}
```

Note that you probably don't need a dictionary at all. Consider replacing it by a list.

Comment: i uses dictionary because the key was startParenthesisIndex and closeParethessIndex was the value ... i needed to remove those index (from start to end)

Comment: It sucks that there's overlap between the index numbers, so you still get into trouble if a later entry begins before an earlier one ends.

Comment: @MrFox That's why I sort start and end parenthesis together

Comment: @Elegiac Of course it depends of what you do with it elsewhere, but for this precise bit of code you don't need to know whether it's an open or close parenthesis

Comment: What do you mean by "from start to end"? Do you have an example?

Comment: @KooKiz like in my question i have the key (openIndex) and value (closeIndex) ... i want to remove the specific index in the string from key(start) to value(end)

Comment: So basically you want to remove what's between the parenthesis? That's way more complicated

Comment: exactly @KooKiz thats what i needed ... sorry about that ... i also mentioned that on my 1st comment in this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` will be more suited to your case as you are continuously changing data. [StringBuilder MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Ordering the keys by descending order will work as well for removing all indexes.

Another workaround could be to place an intermediary character at required index and replace all instances of that character in the end.

```
StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder("ab(cd)");
ab.Remove(2, 1);
ab.Insert(2, "`");
ab.Remove(5, 1);
ab.Insert(5, "`");
ab.Replace("`", "");
System.Console.Write(ab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings when you make a change to a string a new string is always created, so what you want is to create a new string without the removed parts. This code is a little bit complicated because of how it deals with the potential overlap. Maybe the better way would be to cleanup the indexes, making a list of indexes that represent the same removals in the right order without overlap.

```
public static string removeAtIndexes(string source)
{
    var indexes = new Tuple<int, int>[]
    {
        new Tuple<int, int>(15, 19),
        new Tuple<int, int>(16, 18),
        new Tuple<int, int>(19, 21)
    };

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var last = 0;
    bool copying = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        var end = false;

        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            if (copying)
            {
                if (index.Item1 <= i)
                {
                    copying = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (index.Item2 < i)
                {
                    end = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (false == copying && end)
        {
            copying = true;
        }

        if(copying)
        {
            sb.Append(source[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```